# Beyond Compare: Export Differences in two CSV files in CSV format

Tags: excel, csv, beyondcompare

I want to export differences between 2 CSV files and want the export to be present in CSV format.

Using **Beyond Compare** software:

- I can use `text compare` and export differences in csv, but if i use text compare, i cant use keys
- I can use `data compare` which allows me to use keys (by using csv format) but then differences are exported without any separators.

I am using *Session > Data compare report > Side-by-Side* for exporting differences

Any tips/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I exported the differences using side-by-side as HTML Report in data compare report. (Used mono chrome since its size is less)
Then copied the table into excel and saved result as csv.

Not the solution i was expecting but it solved my problem.